# Generated sources being compiled twice

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

Using Eclipse Luna with m2eclipse, I have a parent Maven project (`facturas_root`) and two Maven modules inheriting from it (`sharepoint_ws` and `api_sharepoint`).

`sharepoint_ws` was to be used only to generate JAXWS classes to connect to the Sharepoint WebServices, so I downloaded the related WSDL and included those as resources of the project. At `generate-sources` phase, it works correctly and generates the sources in `target\generated-sources\ws-consume\mypackage\`.

Now, the issue is that I made `api_sharepoint` import the `sharepoint_ws` dependency, but it does not detect any class. I assumed that it was because the generated classes were not at `src/main/java`, so I added a plugin to copy them there. Now, the problem is that at the compile phase of `sharepoint_ws`, it finds twice the source file of each class and throws an error.

My pom.xml -> build

```
<plugins>
  <!-- clean /src/main/java and /target/generated-sources -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/es</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</directory>
            </fileset>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <!-- generate jaxws -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jboss.ws.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jaxws-tools-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2.Final</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>wsconsume</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <wsdls>
              <wsdl>${basedir}/resources/lists.wsdl</wsdl>
            </wsdls>
           <targetPackage>es.ssib.otic.facturas.sharepoint_ws</targetPackage>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <!-- copy sources -->
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
              <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/wsconsume</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
              </resource>
            </resources>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

In order to try to exclude `target/generated-sources` I have addded this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/target/generated-sources/*.java</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

As stated above, I do comment the "copy" plugin, the module depending on `sharepoint_ws` does not have any ot its classes available; I do use it I get errors in the tune of

> [ERROR] /C:/Users/s004256/workspace/facturas_root/sharepoint_ws/src/main/java/es/ssib/otic/facturas/sharepoint_ws/DeleteList.java:[34,8] duplicate class: es.ssib.otic.facturas.sharepoint_ws.DeleteList

for each generated list.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, I recommend you'd better declare `target/generated-sources` as a source folder, instead of copying files here and there:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>add-source</id>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>add-source</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

This should be enough to make Maven compile the target/generated-sources/*.java and package them all in the library, and also for Eclipse to recognize target/generated-sources as a source directory (after you execute Maven/Update Project).

By the way: You should take care of binding the plugins to a phase *in the correct order*: If you bound all tasks to "generate-sources", you have no gurantee about in which order will they be executed. And the same goes for the "compile" phase: You have to set properly the source folders, with its inclusions and exclusions, *before* the compile phase.

Take a look a the [Default Maven Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) and try to chose different, sequential phases for your tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did your change (had to change `initialize` for `validate` in order for it to work, m2e does not recognize several phases), but it did not work; the jar is compiled and with pages in it but the related module still does not access the classes; it looks like the issue is that `/target/classes` is not setup as a "build" folder (it exists in the fileystem but it does not appear in the project explorer).

Comment: Hum... Do you say that the `api_sharepoint` project still can't access the `sharepoint_ws` classes? But, if the `sharepoint_ws-<version>.jar` is well generated, and the dependency is well declared in `api_sharepoint`, it should. Run "mvn dependency:tree" on  `api_sharepoint` to check if the dependency declaration is OK.

Comment: On the other hand: About Eclipse classpath problems: If, for some reason, Eclipse did not recognize target/generated-source as a source folder, go set it manually: click on the folder, show the contextual menu and execute "use as source folder".

Comment: make sure you install the m2e buildhelper connector from Preferences > Maven > Discovery > Open Catalog